# How do I show a log analysis in Splunk?

Tags: server, log

I have made my ubuntu server a centralized log server...I have splunk installed in the /opt directory of the ubuntu server.

I have one of the another machines sending logs to this ubuntu server..In the splunk interface i have added in the network ports as UDP port 514...and also have added in the "file and directory" /var/log.

The client has also been configured properly...How do I show analysis of the logs??

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm what you mean by "How do I show analysis of the logs??"

Splunk has lots of great documentation at http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation

You may be most interested in the user manual: http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation/latest/User/AboutthisUserManual

Splunk won't just do everything magically: http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation/latest/User/AboutthisUserManual

In the same way that Google requires you to type search terms before it gives you what you're looking for, Splunk requires you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using phpLogCon (which has been renamed sometime ago). Just Google "phplogcon" and you should find it, along with its new name. This, along with Apache, and the PHP extension, will let you review log files of different types using a web-based interface. It may be a good start for log reviewing......